# How to use relative path of pictures in excel

Tags: excel, vba, relative-path

I'm working on an excel sheet that contains links to a folder of images on my computer. This sheet will be used on other computers. My aim is that being able to do a relative path, so I can use it in any PC  without updating the path.

```
Sub Vehicle_AddPic()
Dim GetFile As FileDialog

Set GetFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With GetFile
    .Title = "Add Vehicle Picture"
    .Filters.Add "All Picture Files", "*.jpg,*.png,*.gif", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo noselection
    Sheet1.Range("J13").Value = .SelectedItems(1)
    Vehicle_showPic
noselection:
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: The other computers will need to have the images too, or the images need to be on a shared network location - or you need a network share on your machine, and the users on other computers need to have access to that share. That said, unclear what "without updating the path" means, since your code isn't hard-coding any paths, just prompting the user for a file name... user picks a file, that's the file used.

Comment: If the 'pictures folder' is in the same directory as the file (workbook) containing `Sheet1` you could do something like this: `Debug.Print Sheet1.Parent.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Pictures"` or `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Pictures"`.